# Unable to retrieve value from JSON returned by MapQuest API

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json, dom

So, I can't figure out why this won't work:

```
$.getJSON('http://www.mapquestapi.com/geocoding/v1/reverse?key=KEY&callback=renderReverse&json&location=' + lat + ',' + longi, function(geo) {
    $('#location').html(geo.response.results[0].locations[0].adminArea4);
});
```

the returned json is:

```
{
    "results": [
        {
            "locations": [
                {
                    "latLng": {
                        "lng": -1,
                        "lat": 51
                    },
                    "adminArea4": "Hamp",
                    "adminArea5Type": "City",
                    "adminArea4Type": "County",
                    "adminArea5": "Ba and De",
                    "street": "Teal Crescent",
                    "adminArea1": "GB",
                    "adminArea3": "England",
                    "type": "s",
                    "displayLatLng": {
                        "lng": -1.145731,
                        "lat": 51.240441
                    },
                    "linkId": 0,
                    "postalCode": "RG3",
                    "sideOfStreet": "N",
                    "dragPoint": false,
                    "adminArea1Type": "Country",
                    "geocodeQuality": "ADDRESS",
                    "geocodeQualityCode": "L1AAA",
                    "mapUrl": "http://www.mapquestapi.com/staticmap/v4/getmap?key=Fmjtd|luubnu0yn5,7g=o5-9072ur&type=map&size=225,160&pois=purple-1,51.2401563,-1.1463337,0,0|&center=51,-17&zoom=15&rand=-859825484",
                    "adminArea3Type": "State"
                }
            ],
            "providedLocation": {
                "latLng": {
                    "lng": -1.146334,
                    "lat": 51.240156
                }
            }
        }
    ],
    "options": {
        "ignoreLatLngInput": false,
        "maxResults": -1,
        "thumbMaps": true
    },
    "info": {
        "copyright": {
            "text": "© 2013 MapQuest, Inc.",
            "imageUrl": "http://api.mqcdn.com/res/mqlogo.gif",
            "imageAltText": "© 2013 MapQuest, Inc."
        },
        "statuscode": 0,
        "messages": []
    }
}
```

I'm guessing it's because I'm getting the `geo.response.results` bit wrong!

Help would be appreciated.

Comment: change your question title please!

Comment: Are you sure `$('#location').html(` is even executing? I would expect this to fail since you're telling the service to return it as a specific callback with `&callback=renderReverse`, unless the service ignores it and returns CORS headers.

Comment: @KevinB : I changed &callback=renderReverse to &callback=?
It's now working, I grabbed this url from mapquests' api documentation and forgot it was for JavaScript! Thanks very much!

Comment: Your correct kevin, ive put a working example in the answer :)

Comment: @GeorgeTaylor One can still find the API key in the revision history, unfortunately. You could flag your question for moderator attention and explain that situation (they'll remove the complete revision).

Answer (score 3):

There is no `response` key in the returned JSON. Try this:

```
$.getJSON('http://www.mapquestapi.com/geocoding/v1/reverse?key=KEY&callback=renderReverse&json&location=' + lat + ',' + longi, function(geo) {
    $('#location').html(geo.results[0].locations[0].adminArea4);
});
```

Comment: @ComFreek thanks for the edit. Always best to hide your API key, OP.

Comment: Allthough you are correct in your answer if you run it the success is never fired. I debugged and it is because of a syntax error in the json Request Failed: parsererror, SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character

Comment: @ComFreek : Cheers, you were right! (Thanks for the API key hide :))

Answer (score 1):

Although the above answer is correct, there also seems to be a problem with the json your service is returning. It has invalid characters in it casuing your request to return an error.

If you used json success and error messages you will see this

```
var lat = -1.146334;
var longi = 51.240156;


    $.getJSON( 'http://www.mapquestapi.com/geocoding/v1/reverse?key=**YOURKEY**&callback=renderReverse&json&location=' + lat + ',' + longi )
    .done(function( json ) {
    console.log( "JSON Data: " + json);
    })
    .fail(function( jqxhr, textStatus, error ) {
    var err = textStatus + ", " + error;
    console.log( "Request Failed: " + err );
    });
```

The problem is because you are getting json p in your response. To solve this you need to declare jsonp, to get a correct json object.

```
var lat = -1.146334;
var longi = 51.240156;


$.getJSON( 'http://www.mapquestapi.com/geocoding/v1/reverse?key=**YOURKEY**&callback=renderReverse&json&location=' + lat + ',' + longi, {format: "jsonp"} )
.done(function( geo ) {

 $('#location').html(geo.results[0].locations[0].adminArea4);
})
.fail(function( jqxhr, textStatus, error ) {
var err = textStatus + ", " + error;
console.log( "Request Failed: " + err );
});
```